# Using map function instead of for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to find number of lines and words in a file. My input file "testfile.txt' has 6 lines and 23 words. For finding number of words I am using map() function instead of the for loop. When I executed this code it shows the memory location of the object instead of "23":
Number of words =

What am I doing wrong here?

```
def wordcount(l):
    global numwords
    words = l.split()
    numwords += len(words)

f=open('testfile.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
numlines = len(lines)
print ('Number of lines =', numlines)

numwords=0

numwords = map(wordcount, lines)
print ('Number of words =', numwords)
```

Comment: Here is the answer I get "Number of words = <map object at 0x024DF0F0>". I am using Python 3.2 if it helps a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `map` is an iterator: (akin: `itertools.imap`)

```
class map(object)
 |  map(func, *iterables) --> map object
 |  
 |  Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
 |  each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.
```

While in Python 2:

```
map(...)
    map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list
```

It returns a `list` by default.

So in your case, you need to do:

`numwords = list(map(wordcount, lines))`

There are other problems also with your code, but others have pointed that out well enough.

Answer (score 2):

after:

```
numwords = map(wordcount, lines)
```

`numwords` is a list of `None` the same length as `lines` as `wordcount` returns `None`

```
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    numwords += len(words)
```

would be better and more pythonic

Comment: +1, or in one line: `numwords = sum(len(line.split()) for line in lines)`

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid to use a global variable like 'numwords'. You have to return numwords in your wordcount() function.

**This code works :**

```
def wordcount(l):
    numwords = 0
    words = l.split()
    numwords += len(words)
    return numwords

f = open('testfile.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
numlines = len(lines)
print('Number of lines =', numlines)

numwords = 0
numwords = map(wordcount, lines)
print ('Number of words =', numwords)
```

**My testfile.txt contains :**

```
Hello world
my name is
james bond
```

**Ouput** :

```
('Number of lines =', 3)
('Number of words =', [2, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Change the last line to `print ('Number of words =', sum(numwords))` to get the grand total of words.

Answer (score 1):

Read paragraphs to lines and ...

```
print 'Num of words =', reduce(lambda x,y: x+y ,[len(line.split()) for line in lines])
```

Answer (score 0):

function wordcount doesn't return anything, write `return numwords`  Now your function calcualates numwords and then return None by default, and you erase this global variable

Comment: Getting rid of "global declaration helped. Also I had to catch the function's output into a list as @sukhbir pointed out. Following code worked:def wordcount(l):
    numwords=0
    words=l.split()
    numwords += len(words)
    return numwords

file=open('testfile.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
print ('Number of lines =', len(lines))

numwords = list(map(wordcount,lines))
print ('Number of words =', sum(numwords))

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, map either returns a list or iterator, so this modification will work in either case. (python2 vs python3)

```
def wordcount(l):
    global numwords
    words = l.split()
    numwords += len(words)

f=open('testfile.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
numlines = len(lines)
print ('Number of lines =', numlines)

numwords=0

numwords = map(wordcount, lines)
print ('Number of words =', len(list(numwords)))
```